# How to run python script in html using django and get variable from html input form

Tags: python, html, django

i have a sentiment analysis python script, but I want to make it runs in html and get the input form from html page, and the shows the result back in html page.
I already use a django framework to run html page. But i don't know how to connect it with python script I have.

this is my python script

```
query = input("query? \n")
number = input("number of tweets? \n")

results = api.search(
   lang="en",
   q=query + " -rt",
   count=number,
   result_type="recent"
)

print("--- Gathered Tweets \n")

## open a csv file to store the Tweets and their sentiment
file_name = 'Sentiment_Analysis_of_{}_Tweets_About_{}.csv'.format(number, query)

with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
        f=csvfile,
        fieldnames=["Tweet", "Sentiment"]
    )
csv_writer.writeheader()

print("--- Opened a CSV file to store the results of your sentiment analysis... \n")

## tidy up the Tweets and send each to the AYLIEN Text API
   for c, result in enumerate(results, start=1):
      tweet = result.text
      tidy_tweet = tweet.strip().encode('ascii', 'ignore')

      if len(tweet) == 0:
          print('Empty Tweet')
          continue

      response = client.Sentiment({'text': tidy_tweet})
      csv_writer.writerow({
          'Tweet': response['text'],
          'Sentiment': response['polarity']
      })

      print("Analyzed Tweet {}".format(c))

## count the data in the Sentiment column of the CSV file
with open(file_name, 'r') as data:
   counter = Counter()
   for row in csv.DictReader(data):
      counter[row['Sentiment']] += 1

   positive = counter['positive']
   negative = counter['negative']
   neutral = counter['neutral']

## declare the variables for the pie chart, using the Counter variables for 
"sizes"
colors = ['limegreen', 'dodgerblue', 'darkorchid']
sizes = [positive, negative, neutral]
labels = 'Positif', 'Negatif', 'Netral'
explode = (0.1, 0, 0)

## use matplotlib to plot the chart
plt.pie(
    x=sizes,
    shadow=False,
    colors=colors,
    labels=labels,
    startangle=90,
    explode=explode
)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title("Sentiment of {} Tweets about {}".format(number, query))
plt.show()
```

Comment: update post as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In your template file you can have text field

```
        <form method="POST" action="/labdashboard/usergivenlab/">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="textfield" >
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

then in your urls.py define the view

`url(r'usergivenlab/$',views.usergivenlab,name='usergivenlab')`

And in your views.py you can get the use input using the POST method

`usergivenip = request.POST.get('textfield', None)`

Comment: Are there any security risks which one should be aware of, when using such an input form? I read a lot of comments about the "danger" of getting exploited, but I cannot see how a simple input like this could be a problem. 
As I understand, the input text is just saved in a variable and then called within the python script.